# JQuery .hover() not working in IE7 or compatability mode for each version of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I'm building a menu that allows the user to hover over the given topic, and a menu drops down to reveal an array of different options.

Everything works fine in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE9 - IE8 (non-compatability view), but IE7 is doing something weird.

In HTML, my menu is built like this:

```
<div id="menu_container">
<div id="menu_collapse">
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="home_button">
            </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Television</li>
                    <li>Radio</li>
                    <li>Get Involved</li>
                    <li>Non-Profit Services</li>
                    <li>Education</li>
                    <li>Donate</li>
                    <li>Extra</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="search_menu">
                <div id="socialcons">
                    <img src="css/img/twitter.jpg">
                    <img src="css/img/facebook.jpg">
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="search">
                <button></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#menu_container
{
clear:both;
float:left;
width:1000px;
}

#menu
{
float:left;
width:700px;
height:50px;
background-color:#654a6f;
}

#home_button
{
height:50px;
width:40px;
float:left;
background-image:url('img/home.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#menu ul
{
background-color:#485860;
}

#menu li img
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#menu li
{
float:left;
color:#ffffff;
line-height:50px;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #3e204d;
}

#menu li.active
{
background-image:url('img/menu_hover.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom center;
}

#menu li:hover
{
background-image:url('img/menu_hover.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom center;
}

#menu_collapse
{
position:absolute;
float:left;
width:1000px;
height:50px;
background-image:url('img/menu_collapse_bg.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-color:#ffffff;
z-index:99999;
}

#search_menu
{
height:40px;
width:295px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-top:10px;
float:right;
line-height:50px;
background-image:url('img/search_menu.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#search_menu input
{
float:left;
width:140px;
}

#search_menu button
{
height:32px;
width:32px;
border:0;
outline:0;
float:left;
background-image:url('img/search.jpg');
}

#socialcons
{
height:32px;
width:75px;
float:left;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:10px;
line-height:0;
}

#socialcons img
{
margin-left:3px;
}
```

And here is my JQuery, Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#menu li').mouseover(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#menu_collapse').animate({height:'210'}, 300);
    $('#menu li').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
    $('#menu_collapse').hover(function(){},function(){
        $('#menu_collapse').animate({height:'50'}, 300);
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    }); 
});
```

In IE7, and all "compatible" modes with IE, the div #menu_collapsable animates back up when I hover of it, thus defeating the purpose of having it.

Help!!

Comment: If I remember right, you have to set each `#menu li` to `overflow:hidden` for IE. All I've got is hacks. eg. `#menu li { overflow:hidden }` in CSS

Comment: ... did you try it .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() instead?

Comment: yea, it wasn't reacting very well, some browsers wouldn't even notice it left the div...

Comment: I found the answer:

Accredited to the wonderful z-index-ing issue with IE7: 

 var zIndexNumber = 1000;
 $('div').each(function() {
  $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
  zIndexNumber -= 10;
 });

Adding that snipet to my .js fixed my issues... Always the simple stuff that gets you.

I found the answer here: http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu li').hover(
        function(){
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#menu_collapse').animate({height:'210'}, 300);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    );
    $('#menu_collapse').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:'50'}, 300);
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    }); 
});
```